# Is it safe to pass my SSL Key and cert files to Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, https, socket.io

I'm building a web chat using `Socket.IO`

In order to communicate on `Port 3000` through `HTTPS` I need to pass my `SSL Key` and cert files.

`Socket.IO` is an open source project and I don't know how trustworthy it is to allow it to access such secured files as my cert and key files.

Here is the code from `Socket.IO` that runs on the server side by `nodeJS`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('../chat/file.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../chat/file.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

**Is `Socket.IO` is safe to use, security-wise? If not, What are the recommended ways to make it secure?**

**Any help would be MUCH appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: Cross posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/829966/is-it-safe-to-pass-my-ssl-key-and-cert-files-to-socket-io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you have to decide if you trust socket.io at all. It's code you're running on your server.  If it was rogue, it could do all sorts of things to your server environment beyond just your SSL keys.   So, this isn't really an SSL key question at all.  This is just a question about whether you trust socket.io.  It is used by many other servers.  If there was a known reason not to trust its code, that would be fairly publicly shared.  So, I guess you could say, there are no widely known reasons not to trust it.

Second off, most people trust open source projects MORE than they trust closed source projects because the source is available for all to peruse and study and any purposely rogue or nefarious code in these projects would likely be spotted by those paying attention to the project.  Whereas with a closed source project, you have to somewhat blindly trust the intentions and skill of the company you obtain the closed source tool from.  There is no opportunity for public review of closed source code.  I mention this because your question implied that open source code might not be as secure as other types of code and I was disagreeing with that implication.

Third off, you are not actually handing your SSL keys here to socket.io at all.  You're passing them to the https module so it can create your server.  That module is built into node.js.  So, in this case you're really deciding whether you trust node.js or not (which is also an open source project).  Once your server is created, you then pass the already created server to the socket.io module so it can attach an event listener to it.

> Is Socket.IO is safe to use, security-wise?

There is no generic answer to this.  As with nearly all security things, it depends entirely upon what you are trying to protect and what you are trying to protect it from and it depends a lot on the specifics of your implementation.

socket.io, in a nutshell is just a messaging layer on top of a webSocket.

> What are the recommended ways to make it secure?

Again, there is no completely generic answer to this.  Most of securing a socket.io connection is exactly the same as securing a web server.  Secure your server installation and access to it.  Secure the transport with SSL.  Secure the access to the SSL keys.  Design your app's use of all these tools intelligently.  Figure out what you're trying to protect and what you're trying to protect it from and do a very detailed security review with people who are experts in this area.

Comment: Hey jfreind, Your respond is amazing. Thank you so much. You cleared every aspect i've asked about with super knowledgable content. Again. Thank you sir, for sharing priceless information for well-known concerns and issues of beginner developers.